# How do filter the dataframe in such a way?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the output of the dataframe

```
Date    Upper_zone      Lower_zone   Stock_name S/R
0   2018-02-12  163.40   155.75        ABFRL    Resistance becoming support
1   2017-03-16  200.00   189.10        CROMPTON Resistance becoming support
2   2017-04-11  127.69   126.16        CUB      Resistance becoming support
3   2017-02-02  644.40   625.00        ENDURANC Resistance becoming support
4   2019-08-27  15.70    15.20         GMRINFRA Resistance becoming support
5   2020-01-30  1287.00  1233.90       IPCALAB  Resistance becoming support
6   2017-08-01  17236.00 16220.50      PAGEIND  Resistance becoming support
7   2018-09-11  3788.00  3570.00       PFIZER   Resistance becoming support
8   2019-06-20  1261.35  1235.05       PIDILITIND Resistance becoming support
9   2018-09-26  17506.50 16803.40      SHREECEM Resistance becoming support
10  2018-09-03  556.67   542.13          VBL    Resistance becoming support
11  2018-10-31  563.33   533.37          VBL    Resistance becoming support
12  2019-02-06  562.90   534.00          VBL    Resistance becoming support
13  2017-07-05  479.00   461.70        VOLTAS   Resistance becoming support
```

Now I want to have only one stock with the latest date. Here `VBL` is appearing 3 times but I only want one line item of VBl with the latest date. ie.e `2010-02-06` and delete the remaining 2 line items.

here is the code I used group by

```
x  = final_df.groupby('Stock_name')
y = x['Date'].max()
print(y)
```

Output

```
Stock_name
ADANITRANS    2019-08-01
BEL           2019-02-14
BERGEPAINT    2020-01-06
ICICIGI       2019-10-07
INDIGO        2019-01-21
INFY          2019-10-24
MARICO        2017-02-15
RELIANCE      2019-08-07
TCS           2019-01-14
Name: Date, dtype: object
```

How can I add remaining columns with the output that I have received ?

Comment: What is the output of your code?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `drop_duplicate` on column `Stock_name` and keep the last value like this

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset='Stock_name', keep="last")
```

or keep the max value on the `Upper_zone` column like this:

```
df.groupby('Stock_name', group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.Upper_zone.idxmax()])
```

or you can sort the value in `Upper_zone` first, then use the `drop_duplicate` then.

Comment: You can do: ```df.groupby('Stock_name', group_keys=False).last()``` instead of ```apply(...)``` version- should be faster.

Comment: Actually the apply is selecting the `max` value, not just the `last` value tho

Comment: Check the sample data in question - it's the same thing here ;)

Comment: Yes, but I think the answer needs to be more clear, so that others can apply in another dataframe too, you know. Anyway, thank you for your suggestion mate